# "Kein Kandidat" oder "keinen Kandidaten"

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case

Ich möchte in einer Bemerkung hinzufügen, dass es noch kein(en) Kandidat(en) gibt.

Sage ich

> Es gibt noch kein Kandidat.

oder

> Es gibt noch keinen Kandidaten.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sage ich
>
> > Es gibt noch kein Kandidat.

Nein, das ist falsch. Man kann aber sagen

> Es ist noch kein Kandidat verfügbar.

---

> > Es gibt noch keinen Kandidaten.

Das ist korrekt.

Comment: Was hier fehlt: Der Hinweis darauf, dass Akkusativ gefordert ist.

Answer (score 4):

*Es gibt* verlangt anschließend einen Akkusativ. *Kein Kandidat* ist Nominativ, es muss also *keinen Kandidaten* heißen.

> Es gibt kein**en** Kandidat**en**.

Gleiches gilt für *haben*:

> Wir haben noch kein**en** Kandidat**en**.

Anders ist es bei *sein* oder *existieren*. In diesen Fällen ist das Es nicht Subjekt des Satzes sondern lediglich ein syntaktisches Expletiv, das ersatzlos verschwindet, wenn man den Satz umstellt. Stattdessen erfüllt der Kandidat die Rolle des Subjekts, das wie üblich im Nominativ steht.

> Es ist kein Kandidat verfügbar.
>
> Es existiert kein Kandidat.

Answer (score 1):

Allgemein fragst du also, *wen* (Akkusativ) es noch nicht gibt. Die Antwort ist dann ausserdem abhängig vom Geschlecht:

```
Es gibt noch *keinen Kandidaten*. (Maskulinum, Singular)
Es gibt noch *keine Kandidaten*. (Maskulinum, Plural)
Es gibt noch *keine Kandidatin*. (Femininum, Singular) 
Es gibt noch *keine Kandidatinnen*. (Femininum, Plural)
Es gibt noch *keine Kandidatin und keinen Kandidaten*. (gemischt, Singular)
Es gibt noch *keine Kandidatinnen und (keine) Kandidaten*. (gemischt, Plural) 
Es gibt noch *kein Kandidatenschema*. (Neutrum, Singular) 
Es gibt noch *keine Kandidatenschemas*. (Neutrum, Plural)
```